# jQuery data selector doesn't find element that exists

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have scheduler table with divs that represent days. Every day has data-attribute date with the format:

```
$('#scheduler-table > div.row > div:nth-child(4) > div').data()
{date: "8.09.2017", day: 3}
```

Direct selector copied from developer tools.

But when I try to use my selector with data attribute:

```
$('#scheduler-table').find("[data-date='8.09.2017']").data();
```

It doesn't find anything. What is wrong with my selector?

Comment: Have ever read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: Can you provide a html code so that we can reproduce?

Comment: Html code is huge, and I thought that there is sth wrong with my syntax. By the way from the direct selector you can see the structure of scheduler-table. I will delete this post sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: double-check the actual attribute value: http://api.jquery.com/data/ “Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null).”

Comment: I don't understand why convertion of types would be a problem. data date is string format all the time.

Comment: If the data attribute is set using the setter of `data()` it will not appear in the DOM, so an attribute selector will not work. You'll need to use `filter()` instead

Comment: In Firefox: Inspect Element -> Right click on the thing with the `data-date` -> Edit as HTML, copy the tag, but not the contents, edit post :)

Comment: @Mark can you please confirm how the `data` attributes are set on each day element?

Comment: Indeed the problem was connected to what @rory suggested. In order to solve it I changed the way how this data attribute is applied, from data() to attr(). Now it works.

Comment: Don't use `attr()` - it's slower. Use `filter()` properly to work with `data()` instead. I'll add an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue often occurs when you use the setter of `data()` to apply the value, as it does not update the DOM, hence attribute selectors based on the `data` attribute will not find the element. The value is instead stored in an object jQuery maintains as a cache for performance purposes.

To solve the issue, use `filter()` to find the element:

```
var data = $('#scheduler-table > div.row > div:nth-child(4) > div').filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('date') == '8.09.2017';
}).data();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming all you want is to retrieve `data-date`'s value from specific element?

```js
$('#scheduler-table').each(
var mydate = $('#scheduler-table > div.row > div:nth-child(4) > div').attr('data-date')

console.log(mydate);
```

---

## Edited answer:

```js
function SearchByDate(myDate){
    var mySelectedElement;
    $('[data-date]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val(myDate)){
           mySelectedElement = $(this);
        }
    });
}

SearchByDate("8.09.2017");
```

So basically, you search all the attributes with `data-date`, if it's value corresponds to the attribute from `SearchByDate` (a function you call when you please), it will assign the resulting element as `mySelectedElement`.

Comment: OP is trying to select the element by the data attribute, not get the value of the attribute